# Given a linear transformation prove it is one to one

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the transformation $T(ax^2 + bx + c) = (ax^3)/2 + bx^2 + cx$. I know that to prove a transformation is one to one we have to set two polynomials equal to each other and show that all of the variables are equal to their counterpart on the other side.

I'm just having trouble showing that they are equal.

This is what I have so far:

$$q(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$$ and $$u(x) = rx^2 + sx + t$$

$$T(q(x)) = T(u(x)) \implies
(ax^3)/2 + bx^2 + cx = (rx^3)/2 + sx^2 + tx$$

Now I don't know how to show that $a = r, b = s$ and $c = t$

Comment: What property exactly are you trying to prove here? That $T$ is injective or bijective? And most importantly, what are its domain and codomain?

Comment: Your transformation $ T $ is from what to what ?

Comment: Equating coefficients from the $T(q) = T(u)$ equation, you get $a/2 = r/2$, $b = s$, and $c = t$.

Comment: T is the transformation T: P^2 -> P^3.
I just need to prove that the two polynomials are equal and that their components are equal

Comment: Injective (one to one) means you have to show that if two possibly different polynomials are transformed to the same thing, then they are the same polynomial.ie, if T(q(x))=T(u(x)) for every x, then q(x) = u(x) for every x.

Comment: I understand that I equated T(q(x)) = T(u(x)) in that way is it enough to say (ax^3)/2 + bx^2 + cx = (rx^3)/2 + sx^2 + tx and that this shows it is one to one

Comment: Because T(q(x)) = T(u(x)), ie (ax^3)/2 + bx^2 + cx = (rx^3)/2 + sx^2 + tx, equating coefficients shows that a=r, b=s, and c=t. This shows that q(x) = ax^2 + bx + c = rx^2 + sx + t =u(x). Hence T is injective (one to one).

Comment: @Peter I think OP is not familiar with the fact that 2 polynomials are equal iff their coefficients are equal.

Answer (score 1):

You set it up well.  Now just subtract and combine like coefficients, to get $(a/2-r/2)x^3+(b-s)x^2+(c-t)x=0.$

That implies, by the fundamental theorem of algebra, that the coefficients are all zero: $a/2-r/2=0,b-s=0$ and $c-t=0$.  Thus $a=r, b=s$ and $c=t$.

That completes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{a}{2}x^3+bx^2+cx=\frac{r}{2}x^3+sx^2+tx.$$
Differentiating both sides you get:
$$\frac{3a}{2}x^2+2bx+c=\frac{3r}{2}x^2+2sx+t.$$
Differentiate again:
$$3ax+2b=3rx+2s.$$
Again:
$$3a=3r,$$
so $a=r$. Then from previous equality $2b=2s$. Then from the equality before that $c=t.$